# How to concatenate Date and Time columns to form datetime column in SAS Proc sql with DB2 query?

Tags: sql, sas

Can any one help me how to concatenate the Date column Format Date9. (example:- 02MAR2009 ) and Time column Format TIME8. (example:- 8:15:15) and finally creates a new column called "DATETIME" should be in DATETIME25.6 format(Example:- 02MAR2009:08:15:15.000000) in SAS PROC SQL query?

Here the data base is DB2 and all the above mentioned columns(date, time and datetime) are numeric.

I need the code in PROC SQL.

Comment: Are you asking for the DB2 equivalent of the DHMS() function in SAS?  Why not just pull the DATE and TIME separately from DB2 and run the DHMS() funciton on the SAS side of the query?  Or do you need to update the tables in DB2?

Comment: Are you using SAS SQL or DB2 SQL? If so, you need DB2 code, not SAS code.

Answer (score 1):

The `DHMS` function can do this for you.  You don't need to set the hours and minutes, since the time value is the number of seconds since the previous midnight.

```
data _null_;
x = '02mar2009'd;
y = '08:15:15't;
z = dhms(x,0,0,y);
format x date9. y time8. z datetime25.6;
put _all_;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the responce and the DHMS function is working in datastep, but not in Proc SQL with DB2 connection...

Comment: Apologies, I didn't check for that